# Firefox: Open tab in other window?

Tags: firefox, window, browser-tabs

I recently got a second monitor, and I have found myself using it with a second browser window open, viewing secondary pages that I may want to quickly look at while using my primary monitor.

**The problem** is that the current method for getting pages to this monitor is clumsy.  I first have to open the page in a new tab, then manually move the tab to the window on my second monitor.  What I would like is a menu option similar to "Open Link in New Tab" and "Open Link in New Window", except it would be "Open Link in New Tab in the Other Window".

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read question attentively enough. Leaving this answer anyway You can read about this option [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/quick-tip-duplicate-current-tab-in-new-window-in-firefox/) It required installing add-on, but IMHO it's rather good even if you don't open tabs in new windows.

Comment: You can eliminate one step by just dragging the link that you want to open onto the tab bar of the second window. Not exactly what you want though...

Answer (score 4):

Because you can have as many windows as you like, the "other window" quickly becomes meaningless. There isn't really a perfect solution to this problem, as far as I'm aware, but one way you could speed up the process is by dragging the link in question directly to the tab bar of the second window. This should open it up in that window, saving you a mouse movement.

Answer (score 2):

Drag the tab PAST the extreme edge of the second monitor.

So, if the second monitor is to the right of the main monitor, drag the tab past the right edge of the monitor. Hey presto!

I was trying top do the same as you and tried everything...this worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tab bar visible on the destination window, you can just drag the tab from one window to the other by dropping the tab on the tab bar.

One of my friends just told me that you can just drag the link over to the other browser to have it open it as well.

Comment: i suppose, that's what prattnic meant with: "I first have to open the page in a new tab, then manually move the tab to the window on my second monitor." he probably wants to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that windows (as in the plural of window, not the OS) can remember the last position that they were opened in. If you open your browser and drag it to the second monitor, it might help. Also, check your display settings. Sometimes, there are different modes. (clone/extend) Perhaps messing with that may help. Also, look at nVidia / ATI control panel settings.

Comment: Getting new windows to open on the second monitor isn't a problem, but I want links to open in a new tab in an already opened window on the second monitor.

Comment: You essentially want the new tabs to open in a window that you already have open. I don't know that is possible. Sorry.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a custom FF add-on

Answer (score 0):

On my Firefox (3.5.5) on Windows, Tabs can be dragged. Dragging a tab to to the desktop opens a new Firefox window populated with just that tab, and tabs can be dragged between Firefox windows.  I am not sure if that is exactly what you are are wanting, but does allow tabs to be moved between windows.

Answer (score 0):

all i could suggest is that you use shift + click to open the link in a new window and search the internet for an easy way to send the window maximised to the other monitor

i just did a little surfing and people reccommend ultramon not sure if it is free but apparently it adds a button to send maximized to the other monitor

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Answer (score 0):

If you middle mouse click on the link it will open in a new tab, you can then drag this tab outside the current window to the other screen.

Alternatively, you can probably do what you want and a whole lot more with the incredible 'tab mix plus'

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122

Answer (score 0):

There are currently a few solutions that rely on the context menu in [Add-ons for Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/), such as [Tab Mover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mover/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) and [Move Tab to Next Window](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/move-tab-to-next-window/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search). See also [How to make new windows open on different displays?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1020379) for related search terms.

If you have one of those installed, you can use [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/881728/shortcut-key-to-detach-a-tab-in-firefox-move-tab-to-new-window/1645694#1645694) from a question about how to detach a tab to get to the context menu using only your keyboard. Given the inconvenience of getting to the tab bar, you may want to "batch move" all tabs that should have been on your other monitor using the ["Selection of Multiple Tabs" section of the Keyboard shortcuts Firefox Documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_selection-of-multiple-tabs).