# Detach a tab in firefox (move tab to new window), Firefox 58

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-addons, firefox-quantum

> In FF, I can move a tab to a new window by either dragging the tab out
>   of the browser, or right clicking the "move to New window" option from
>   the context menu. is there a shortcut key to move the current tab to a
>   new window without dragging or using the context menu, or a way to set
>   one up?

This question was answered for older versions of FF (see [shortcut key to detach a tab in firefox (move tab to new window)](https://superuser.com/questions/881728/shortcut-key-to-detach-a-tab-in-firefox-move-tab-to-new-window?newreg=d8042d2d0d3545af86800fd828780a67) )
The solution used [Keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994), which is no longer supported by FF 58.
There is a somewhat similar tool, called [Shortkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/).

However, the code proposed in the solution to the earlier question

```
window.openDialog("chrome://browser/content/browser.xul","_blank","chrome,dialog=no,all",gBrowser.mCurrentTab);
```

doesn't work if one uses the option to "Run JavaScript" in the settings of Shortkeys.

Is there any idea how to fix this and/or how to use the great functionality of detaching tabs with shortcuts from FF 58 onwards?

Of course I did check the [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs) but couldn't find the right shortcut.

Comment: Good question, but note I wouldn't expect any `chrome://` URI to work in FF :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks for your hint but I think it was quite usual before. See e.g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Chrome_Registration

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that article is referring to chrome the browser.

Comment: @SeanAllred but if I'm not wrong, neither does the command above?

Comment: Well I'll be damned; I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:**: I've uploaded a new signed extension that moves the active tab to a new window on Ctrl+Shift+1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUVSWvgRXPPmtjYl5am-dn9a6JEEzzGO/view?usp=sharing. The shortcut isn't intuitive, but without knowing the platform Firefox is running on, I have to plan for compatibility.

Sorry about the first edit; I uploaded the wrong extension by accident. The one in the link above should meet the criteria from the question.

<del>**Edit:** A signed version of the extension is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19okZRGCQa5pGH08HD2ml9D2TQcStnk0Q/view?usp=sharing</del>

<del>**Old Answer:**</del>

<del>I made a Firefox WebExtension that moves the active tab to a new window on `Ctrl+Shift+0`. It's unsigned, but you can easily verify for yourself that the 46 lines of code aren't malicious.</del>

<del>You can try it out in Nightly by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false and clicking `[Install Add-on From File...]` in the gear menu in `about:addons`. I think unsigned extensions can still be temporarily installed on release builds of Firefox through `[Load Temporary Add-on]` in `about:debugging`.</del>

You are free to modify the extension source to suit your needs or ask me to do so.

<del>https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zRmAy-EHB4EspY_d9WVbXpddBJA9l48W/view?usp=sharing</del>

Comment: Thanks for the signed version (and sorry for my slow reply). It seems that one cannot really detach a tab from an active browser window. It works fine to move tabs around (i.e. I have two open windows and can move the tabs from one to another), but it seems that creating a new windwo with the selected tab doesn't work. Do you have any thoughts how that could work? Thanks again for your help and your effort!

Comment: On a Mac, use Cmd-Shift-1 instead of Ctrl-Shift-1 (doesn't do anything on a Mac).

Comment: This is great. Is your code on github/are you looking for feedback?

Comment: As of August 2020, Cmd-Shift-1 is opening a container tab on a Mac.  Don't know how to make this work again. @user873319