# Firefox: Shortcut Key to move a tab to a new window?

Tags: firefox

Is there such a key or a way to create one to move a tab to a new window? Currently I have to right click > move tab> move to new window.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shortcut key to detach a tab in firefox (move tab to new window)](https://superuser.com/questions/881728/shortcut-key-to-detach-a-tab-in-firefox-move-tab-to-new-window)

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but you can do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> from address bar to open the address to a new window.

You can also drag the tab with your mouse out of the current window. Then it will be in it's own window.

Comment: You can select the address bar by Ctrl-L.