# Firefox: Is it possible to detach a tab from a window with the keyboard?

Tags: firefox

I am referencing the action you can make by dragging a tab out of the top bar, which creates a new window wherein to put the dragged tab.

Comment: Reading through the list on https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs it appears not...

Comment: Depends what platform you're on, but Safari can do that [or rather it has a menu command to do it, to which you could easily add your own shortcut key command.] https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ2RO.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shortcut key to detach a tab in firefox (move tab to new window)](https://superuser.com/questions/881728/shortcut-key-to-detach-a-tab-in-firefox-move-tab-to-new-window)

Comment: @Tetsujin What is this need to impose your tastes on others ? My post literally starts with "Firefox", and you answer something about Safari... If I was asking for other browsers alternatives, I would have said so.

Comment: "Imposing my taste" is a bit strong for what was meant to be a helpful suggestion for a possible alternative. Remind me not to bother trying to help you ever again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok so next time someone asks how to create any kind of variable in C, recommend them Python "Easier. No worry about type". 

The very purpose of stack.* is to store solutions to the specific question asked, in order to aggregate information so that people find it more and more easily. Think about posterity : how good would it be to the community if, when trying to do a specific action with some technology they are used to, they get told to use another technology. This is simply not a good strategy to organize information, which is what Stack Exchange was specifically designed to.

Comment: I think you need to get out of the other side of the bed sometime. Go ahead, try it, you might feel better for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native option for this, but you can achieve this by using the [Shortkeys add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/)

In **Shortkeys options**, in the **behavior** dropdown, in the **Tabs** category, there is a **Move tab to new window** command.

You can create a keyboard shortcut for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a 1 shortcut to achieve this, but you could do that with several shortcuts:

1. Ctrl-L # Focus on URL in current window.
2. Ctrl-C # Copy it.
3. Ctrl-W # Close current tab.
4. Ctrl-N # Open new window.
5. Ctrl-V # Paste.
6. Enter  # Open URL in new window.

Comment: This doesn't "detach" the tab though, but rather opens a new instance. This essentially reloads the page which detaching doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-L, Shift-tab 3 times, Shift-F10, v, w.

The sequence above focuses the address bar, then focuses the tab, then calls the tab context menu, then opens the Move Tab submenu, then selects Move to New Window.

--

Sometimes I'll right-click on a tab then type v, w to accomplish the same thing. Seems cleaner somehow then dragging the tab to move it to a new window.